# Too much white space around subplots in 3d projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, whitespace, subplot

I cannot figure out how to reduce the margins around the subplots in the case of 3d projection. I tried *subplots_adjust* but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(19.2, 10.8), 
                         subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'), constrained_layout=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.0, 1, 0.94])
fig.savefig('trial.png', format='png', dpi=220)
fig.show()
```

[subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coAoU.jpg)

Comment: it happens when I use the new matplotlib version 3.5.2 yet it does not happen in earlier versions such as 3.1.2.

Comment: ```constrained_layout```, ```fig.tight_layout``` and even ```plt.subplots``` can be a bit tricky with white spaces. Maybe you could consider using [Matplotlib Gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) and trim the image using ```wspace```, ```hspace```, etc...